# OK to assign one NSObject as the delegate of multiple ASIHTTPRequests?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, delegates, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

Is it OK to assign one `NSObject` as the delegate of multiple, asynchronous `ASIHTTPRequest`s?

My concern is that two or more requests will call the same callback method on the delegate at the same time.

I checked that `ASIHTTPRequest` calls the delegate callbacks on the main thread, just as `NSURLConnection` does. So, it's OK, right?

Comment: Why would you want one instance of same object as a delegate for few objects? I think separate instances would work quite nice!

Comment: Because I made a subclass of `ASIHTTPRequest` called `JSONRequest` that is the delegate... Actually, I just realized that I *am* creating separate instances. Each instance of `JSONRequest` is its own delegate, handles the callbacks, and passes them on to `jsonDelegate`, which is a private property of `JSONRequest` and responds to `requestFinished:withResult:`, where result is an `NSDictionary` representation of the JSON response. To do this, I overloaded setDelegate: to do `super.delegate = self; self.jsonDelegate = newDelegate`. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine, normal, and part of the design of delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfectly normal thing to do. Properly designed APIs should pass the calling object as a parameter of any delegate methods. This way, an object acting as a delegate can (if necessary) distinguish its delegate responsibilities by delegating object instance.